# Web development environment with C++ in PHP manner

Tags: c++, apache

I've searched and googled, yes, yes, C++ isn't meant for web - enough!

I am looking for a way to write my web app in C++, in a way like PHP handles it - compile on request.

I bet it'd be done through CGI, but the question is, how do I set up such environment in, for example, Apache?

Lets assume, that my document root has `index.cpp` with the good old `Hello World` example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

And the request to `localhost/index.cpp` would end up printing `Hello World` to my browser.

This is meant for development only, production app would get pre-compiled and only then served (but that's a question for future).

P.S. I have never written C++, am willing to learn. Willing to learn by Web Development.

Comment: Forget CGI, [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/) is what you're looking for. (No affiliation)

Comment: CGI doesn't work after the principle "compile on request". This is not very sensible for a language like C or C++. You need to compile the program first, then you can use it as a CGI script (but you need to output headers before the body).

Comment: (Also you tagged the question C++, wrote "C/C++" in the title and then showed "hello world" in rather old style C - you should explicitly pick one)

Comment: @Niklas B, isn't there a way to automate it? Like, server reads `*.cpp` has been requested, it issues compilation and on compile reads result back? Or I'd have to develop Apache Module for it? @awoodland, changed to C++.

Comment: @Tom: Compilation on demand would be much too slow. Why do you need that anyways?

Comment: Stop those close votes please. This is perfectly on-topic, comprehensible, and answerable. If you think it’s just weird – well, I think it’s weird coding large applications in something like PHP.

Comment: @Niklas B, Note the "meant for development only". And, I want to learn C++ by making Web stuff, that's how I learnt PHP. PHP, though, is not enough anymore, but I love the auto-compilation/execution.

Comment: @NiklasB. As explained in the question, this is to make development simpler. The final application would start off pre-compiled.

Comment: @Tom: You can use something like `fileschanged` to start `make` everytime you change something. No need to do it on a web request.

Comment: Most non-trivial applications have more than one source file that goes into the final executable, so making a request for a specific file in a project doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MaxVT, yes, yes... That's an example, that translates to: on request webserver issues compiler to compile the stuff that corresponds to the file requested and displays the result after compilation (well, something along those lines). Just that it has to be automated.

Comment: Tom: You need a proper Makefile one way or the other. Then you can use `mod_rewrite` to redirect all your requests to a single script (PHP?), which `make`s the associated C executable and runs it. But the usual way would be to call `make` manually or automatically on file change and execute the programs as CGI.

Comment: As @awoodland I think you need a library. I suggest you [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for a C++ interpreter... hmm, I'm not sure there are any. C++ is a compiled language, meaning you develop the source then run it through a tool (a compiler) to generate native binaries. These can then be called by the OS and are as fast as you can get - as everything is turned into stuff the computer can understand already. With PHP the 'turn into stuff the computer can understand' has to happen while the computer is executing the code!

Of course it means you don't have the luxury of changing the source code during execution, you have to stop, modify, then start again. With a web based system, this isn't so bad unless you store state inside your C++ application, if it's truly stateless then you can just kill the running process, recompile it and start it up again.

For advanced usage though, you can run the program inside an interactive debugger. Some of these allow you to modify your code and have it automatically recompiled so it appears to you just like you're running your PHP code.  The difficulty is getting the debugger set up to run with the rest of your system (ie as often the debugger starts the process, whereas normally Apache starts the process)

So... to do what you want. I'd go with the debugger approach. Set apache to run a single instance of your program, not start a new one up. This will require CGI or FastCGI setup. Once that's done, you manually start your process running, by starting it in the debugger. Set a breakpoint in the places where your app will be called. Write your service to be multithreaded so only one running instance is required, you do not start a new one for each request. I'd recommend using FastCGI and configuring your app as a [FastCgiExternalServer](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiExternalServer) type.

Typically though you want to keep your code in PHP in Apache, and use this to call into a C++ based service. This allows you a lot more security (as if the web server gets hacked, the most the attacker can do is call the entrypoints to your C++ service, they don't have full access to everything, a lot of places do this type of architecture) and scalability (as the service could be hosted on 1 or more application servers).

I'd recommend asking on ServerFault for Apache config advice.